# Android JsonArray into ListView

Tags: android, json

Im trying to parse json array data into listview!I searched the whole internet and always was on one point! Json aray must have header something like this

```
"emp_info":[{"employee name":"Adam","employee no":"101700"},{"employee name":"John","employee no":"101701"},{"employee name":"Paul","employee no":"101702"},{"employee name":"Mark","employee no":"101703"},{"employee name":"Donald","employee no":"101704"},{"employee name":"Brain","employee no":"101705"},{"employee name":"Kevin","employee no":"101706"}]}
```

Where by my understanding the `"emp_info"` is the header file by which i must search for rest data inside it in android!My College pretending that i can accept and parse the same data into listview without that header name,but every bit of code where i searched to parse json in android was a single line like this!

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray stations = obj.getJSONArray("emp_inf");
```

where i just have to put the jsonarray header file as you can see in this piece of code!So please help me is that possible to accept json array without this code?because if i try to remove this code i get nullpointer in my code!Will be very happy if you could at least say yes or no!
Posting Full Codes!
Here is the android class which gets the Json and loads it into List View

```
    private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://54.148.41.171/server/index/dompy");
try {
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
}

catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
String rLine = "";
StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

try {
while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
answer.append(rLine);
}
}

catch (IOException e) {
// e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return answer;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
ListDrwaer();
}
}// end async task

public void accessWebService() {
JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
// passes values for the urls string array
task.execute(new String[] { url });
}

// build hash set for list view
public void ListDrwaer() {
List<Map<String, String>> employeeList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

try {
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("emp_info");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
String name = jsonChildNode.optString("empployee no");
String number = jsonChildNode.optString("etc.");
String outPut = name + "-" + number;
employeeList.add(createEmployee("data", outPut));
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
new String[] { "employee no" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private HashMap<String, String> createEmployee(String name, String number) {
HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
employeeNameNo.put(name, number);
return employeeNameNo;
}


}
```

And by this json array im successfully able to fetch the json which type is the next!

```
 {"emp_info":[{"employee name":"Adam","employee no":"101700"},{"employee name":"John","employee no":"101701"},{"employee name":"Paul","employee no":"101702"},{"employee name":"Mark","employee no":"101703"},{"employee name":"Donald","employee no":"101704"},{"employee name":"Brain","employee no":"101705"},{"employee name":"Kevin","employee no":"101706"}]}
```

And here is the  json array which my college pretends that i must accept!

```
{"data":"123"}
```

And im Saying that its not possible to load this json into list view just because it dont have header file like mine the `emp_info`,but hes saying its not matter i just MUST accept!We just on same project and i just cant understand is it even possible to do what he says?

Comment: That json is not valid.

Comment: The posted is your full json? then its not a valid one.

Comment: No its a pice of json ill edit it now and post full json,the thing is that im able to do all perfect with this way but because my college is php server side master he says that i must accept it without that header name i just posted about and im gettin frasturade as hell!

Comment: Now i editid with full json which i get echoed in my way and im able to retrieve all this and load into ListView successfully,unfortunattally my college says that im wrong and i must able to accept without emp_info header stroke,and i just cant find any piece of code which dont needs that field to be filled!

Comment: Well, if it is working then what is wrong? Not following the coding standards? Post the whole code related to parsing, lets see what can be done.

Comment: Thank you so much ill do it right now,no its just a matter like my college pretending he's the hella knows everything!!:S I'm just trying to see if I'm wrong well do it his way so its my wrong code,but if I'm right well do it my way,we just on same project...i just needed to know can i accept another json without header stroke,anyway ill post full code now

Comment: I just need to see the part where you're parsing the Json.

Comment: {"emp_info":[{"employee name":"Adam","employee no":"101700"},{"employee name":"John","employee no":"101701"},{"employee name":"Paul","employee no":"101702"},{"employee name":"Mark","employee no":"101703"},{"employee name":"Donald","employee no":"101704"},{"employee name":"Brain","employee no":"101705"},{"employee name":"Kevin","employee no":"101706"}]}

validated json

Comment: ok i did put all codes!please HELP!!:( hes pissing me off!

Comment: you can append the header to the json string yourself, and you can iterate through Json objects without the header file

Comment: Ok i got it,so it means my college was right i can request accept and parse the json array into listview without header got it....so whats the code for it then?Because if i remove the code in java where it needs to put the header field i just get nullpointer at that line..

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = jsonChildNode.optString("empployee no");
String number = jsonChildNode.optString("etc.");
```

How can you get the data by "etc." tag I could not understand it firstly. It should return "" instead of employee number.

Comment: Oh Sorry it was handmade typness i just when was coping the code typed etc. to pass it quick i still instead of etc. gettin the employee no parameters!